# Push two files with similar names using git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a repo looking like this

```
repo/
  folder/
    abc
    abcdef
```

where `abc` is a library I'd like to track with git-lfs and `abcdef` is another library that doesn't needs to be tracked with git-lfs.

In `repo` I did

```
git lfs track --filename "folder/abc"
```

then .gitattributes was generated with

```
folder/abc filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

However, when I git add everything and make a push, this error came up

```
LFS upload failed:cts:  50% (1/2), 151 MB | 0 B/s
  (missing) folder/abcdef (<hash>)
hint: Your push was rejected due to missing or corrupt local objects.
hint: You can disable this check with: 'git config lfs.allowincompletepush true'
Uploading LFS objects:  50% (1/2), 151 MB | 0 B/s, done.
```

It seems for some reason git-lfs wants to track `folder/abcdef` as well.

Why does this happen? Is it because the name of the file I want to track ('abc') is a substring of 'abcdef'? How to get around this and only let git-lfs track `folder/abc` but not `folder/abcdef`?

Comment: try to add a final $ in .gitattributes

Comment: this specific pattern shouldn't apply to your file `abcdef`. You can check the attributes that apply to a target file by running: `git check-attr -a -- folder/abcdef`. Perhaps your abcdef file falls in lfs tracked files for another reason.